# Detect webgl support, should we use Detector.js or system.min.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js

It seems like Detector.js is used more often when I look around online, but I see that there is also the minified system.min.js file: https://github.com/mrdoob/system.js

This may be trivial, but I'm wondering which is proper to use, and why most people seem to be using Detector (from what I've seen, at least). They both seem to do the task.

Comment: If they both do the same thing, it probably doesn't matter. Just pick one.

Answer (score 5):

It appears that [System.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/system.js/blob/master/src/System.js) and [Detector.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/examples/js/Detector.js) both use the same snippet of code for detecting WebGL. Namely:

```
var supportsWebGL = ( function () { try { return !! window.WebGLRenderingContext && !! document.createElement( 'canvas' ).getContext( 'experimental-webgl' ); } catch( e ) { return false; } } )();
```

If that's all you need to detect, you could just use that directly.